# The Original Quote in Japanese from "Kafka on the Shore" by Murakami

Tags: quotes

Folks,

Curious if anyone knows the original version of this wonderful quote from "Kafka on the Shore" by Murakami?

> “And once the storm is over, you won’t remember how you made it through, how you managed to survive. You won’t even be sure, whether the storm is really over. But one thing is certain. When you come out of the storm, you won’t be the same person who walked in. That’s what this storm’s all about.”

I would appreciate if someone can share the original Japanese version!

Comment: The part beginning そしてその砂嵐が終わったとき in this link? http://blog.livedoor.jp/yossan69/archives/52563312.html

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this question is on-topic.

Comment: @jarmanso7 I'm quite certain it is off-topic but it intrigued me nonetheless.

Comment: @user3856370 Thanks a lot! If you want to formalize this as a response, I will select it so that the communicate can benefit from it!